# Why does my custom DOM Event not reach my event listener?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

Here's my code, it's based off the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/Creating_and_triggering_custom_events) provided at MDN:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var element = document.createElement('div');

    var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("myClick", true, false);

    element.dispatchEvent(event);

    document.addEventListener("myClick", function(){
        alert("myClick event caught");
    }, false);
}
```

When I run this, nothing happens, indicating something went wrong in the creation, sending or catching of the event. I would appreciate any help in understanding where I am going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Pablo Fernandez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7595/pablo-fernandez) is right in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057674/problem-creating-basic-custom-dom-event/7057762#7057762) about the order, but another component is that your element needs to be in the DOM.

The reason is that you're making the event a bubbling event, and attaching the handler to the `document`. Well in order for the event to bubble up to the `document`, the element it's bubbling from needs to be *within* the `document`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nhsN4/

```
window.onload = function(){
    var element = document.createElement('div');

        // add element to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild( element );

    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");

    evt.initEvent("myClick", true, false);

        // add listener to the document
    document.addEventListener("myClick", function(){
        alert("myClick event caught");
        alert( event.type );
    }, false);

        // dispatch the event on the element, and it bubbles up to the document
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

---

If you had added the handler directly to the `element` you created, then you could dispatch the event without it being in the `document`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nhsN4/1/

```
window.onload = function(){
    var element = document.createElement('div');

    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");

    evt.initEvent("myClick", true, false);

    // add listener to the element
    element.addEventListener("myClick", function(){
        alert("myClick event caught");
        alert( event.type );
    }, false);

    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the code is in the wrong order, seems like `dispatchEvent` fires the event, so it must be after the `addEventListener` call.